dj-rest-auth with Google Login: TypeError: OAuth2Provider.get_scope() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
I'm trying to set up dj-rest-auth with Google.
Configured as follows:
settings.py:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "corsheaders",
    "rest_framework",
    "rest_framework.authtoken",
    "allauth",
    "allauth.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.google",
    "dj_rest_auth",
    "dj_rest_auth.registration",

    ...
]

...

REST_AUTH = {
    "USE_JWT": True,
    "JWT_AUTH_COOKIE": "access",
    "JWT_AUTH_REFRESH_COOKIE": "refresh",
}

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'dj_rest_auth.jwt_auth.JWTCookieAuthentication',
    ),
    ...
}


SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    "google": {
        "EMAIL_AUTHENTICATION": True,
        "FETCH_USER_INFO": True,
        "SCOPE": ["profile", "email"],
        "APP": {
            "client_id": "my-client-id",
            "secret": "my-secret",
        },
        "AUTH_PARAMS": {
            "access_type": "online",
        }
    }
}

...

views.py:
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.google.views import GoogleOAuth2Adapter
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.oauth2.client import OAuth2Client
from dj_rest_auth.registration.views import SocialLoginView


class GoogleLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = GoogleOAuth2Adapter
    callback_url = "http://localhost:8000/auth/google/callback"
    client_class = OAuth2Client

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
        kwargs["context"] = self.get_serializer_context()
        return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)

urls.py:
from django.urls import path, include

from .views import GoogleLogin

urlpatterns = [
    path("", include("dj_rest_auth.urls")),
    path("google/", GoogleLogin.as_view(), name="google"),
    path("registration/", include("dj_rest_auth.registration.urls")),
]

(this is in an app with url /auth/)
When I get the code from google and post it to /auth/google/, I get the following error:
Internal Server Error: /auth/google/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gl/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vtk_backend-Ry6OzTQz-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/gl/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vtk_backend-Ry6OzTQz-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/gl/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vtk_backend-Ry6OzTQz-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 65, in _view_wrapper
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/gl/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vtk_backend-Ry6OzTQz-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 104, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/gl/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vtk_backend-Ry6OzTQz-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 48, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/gl/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vtk_backend-Ry6OzTQz-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py", line 143, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/gl/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vtk_backend-Ry6OzTQz-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dj_rest_auth/views.py", line 48, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/gl/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vtk_backend-Ry6OzTQz-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/gl/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vtk_backend-Ry6OzTQz-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/gl/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vtk_backend-Ry6OzTQz-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/gl/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vtk_backend-Ry6OzTQz-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/gl/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vtk_backend-Ry6OzTQz-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dj_rest_auth/views.py", line 125, in post
    self.serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
  File "/home/gl/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vtk_backend-Ry6OzTQz-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 223, in is_valid
    self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/gl/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vtk_backend-Ry6OzTQz-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 445, in run_validation
    value = self.validate(value)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/gl/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vtk_backend-Ry6OzTQz-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dj_rest_auth/registration/serializers.py", line 122, in validate
    scope = provider.get_scope(request)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: OAuth2Provider.get_scope() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

It seems there is a problem in the SocialLoginSerializer of dj-rest-auth.
If I override this Serializer with a custom GoogleLoginSerializer, and remove request from get_scope(). I get a 400 Bad Request with no information.

did you ever figure this out?

  File "/Users/decoherence/repos/aer-py/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dj_rest_auth/views.py", line 125, in post
    self.serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
  File "/Users/decoherence/repos/aer-py/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 223, in is_valid
    self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/decoherence/repos/aer-py/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 445, in run_validation
    value = self.validate(value)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/decoherence/repos/aer-py/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dj_rest_auth/registration/serializers.py", line 122, in validate
    scope = provider.get_scope(request)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: OAuth2Provider.get_scope() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given



Judging from the last sentence, "If I override this Serializer with a custom GoogleLoginSerializer, and remove request from get_scope(). I get a 400 Bad Request with no information.", it would seem that Giles did, even if he didn't get a good outcome. This is a pertinent question to Giles but it's not an answer.

Downgrade django-allauth to 0.61.1 get rid of this issue.

pip install django-allauth==0.61.1

Currently suspect django-allauth > 0.61.1 changes the implementation of provider that breaks dj-rest-auth's SocialLoginSerializer
https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth/issues/639
